# Webserver not responding - not sure what's wrong

Tags: php, apache2, php7

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Linux pinf-vps 4.4.0-97-generic #120-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 19 17:28:18 UTC 2017 x86_64
PHP Version 7.1.10-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (php-fpm)
Ubuntu 16.04.1
8GB RAM, 4 cores (Azure A4_V2)
```

- Network (24 h): https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GQsi2j6.png
- CPU (24 h): https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GQsiB6z.png

Apache isn't sometimes reacting. I'm hosting there couple of websites, but they don't get super-big traffic. I thought it might be caused by MySQL firstly, but it sometimes affects website which doesn't use it.

I have no idea what could be causing the problem.
The web would hang for 5 - 120 seconds which is waaay too long. 
Sometimes it's not responding for 20 minutes.
And sometimes only the MySQL based web (with Wordpress, btw: the same WP page runs fast on other hosting)

ulimit -a

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31742
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31742
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I can post outputs of various commands.
It's driving me crazy.
Firstly I thought it's DDOS, but I was wrong. 
What can I do to fix it?

```
EDIT: It was down for some time now, I have the logs:
[Wed Oct 25 05:05:03.192874 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16511:tid 140363339585280] [client **.**.253.4:22300] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Wed Oct 25 05:40:38.481107 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16511:tid 140363490653952] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 192.0.91.177:24513] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
[Wed Oct 25 05:41:11.587027 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16510:tid 140363457083136] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 210.4.124.13:18651] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
[Wed Oct 25 05:41:48.509292 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16510:tid 140363490653952] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 210.4.124.13:18703] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
[Wed Oct 25 05:43:20.751238 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16510:tid 140363599685376] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 192.0.91.61:27200] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: https://www.**********.**/xmlrpc.php?for=jetpack&token=**************%3A1%3A1&timestamp=1508902698&nonce=orjewRjNCU&body-hash=****************&signature=**************
[Wed Oct 25 06:05:03.605511 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16511:tid 140363465475840] [client 92.240.253.4:62965] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
[Wed Oct 25 06:25:07.270569 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16507:tid 140364126173056] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Wed Oct 25 06:25:08.159906 2017] [so:warn] [pid 16507:tid 140364126173056] AH01574: module http2_module is already loaded, skipping
```

Comment: Anything interesting on Apache logs? And what do you mean by "Apache is not reacting?"

Comment: @ThoriumBR I included the logs.